# FullCalendar display week events like it is in ''months"

Tags: fullcalendar

i'm building a system using the fullcalendar plugin and i have one problem.
When there is a couple of events on the same day, the way it is displayed on `week view` is too confusing. 
Here is an actual image from the page:
[image] 
I'd like to know if is it possible to change it to be like it's in the month view. When have more than `n` events, then it will show the `more +n` button.

```
 $('#agenda').fullCalendar({
    windowResize: function(view) {},
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: 3,
    eventOverlap: false,
    slotEventOverlap: false,
    height:800,
    allDaySlot: false,
    [... more code ...]
 });
```

Comment: Try using "basicWeek" view.. It has what you wanted. I'm using in my application.

Comment: @Prasanth chinja Can you give me an example? I didn't understod where to put it. I update the question with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this.. The basicWeek view will not have any spaces if events are not there..

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek'
            },
            allDayDefault: false,
            slotDuration: '00:15:00',
            allDaySlot: true,
            defaultView: 'basicWeek' // basicWeek does what you need, either call the view or set as defaultView
 });
```

How it is in my app :

[image: I'm listing events one by one in the Week view where no spaces is available]

Comment: Thank you sir! I didn't tought it was supposed to change the default view. But now, it's more organized.